# Is there a way to set variables in ssh?

Tags: mysql, ssh

Still working my way around this, but is there any function/command I can use to set some simple variables?

Logging into mysql is quicker when I'm already ssh'd in, but typing in the full connection string is a bit annoying.

Any way to do something like:

```
mysql ${variable} dbname
```

Where `variable` would be something like `-u user -p -h hostname`

Or, is there another way to do what I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create **alias** in your `~/.bash_profile` (on the server). Changes in `~/.bash_profile` will have effect the next time you log in.

For example add

```
alias conMy='mysql -u user -p -h hostname'
```

And then use it via

```
ssh yourServer conMy dbname
```

or when already logged on, just:

```
conMy dbname
```

---

From the bash manpage:

> **alias** [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>       Alias with no arguments or with the -p option prints the list of
>   aliases in the form alias name=value
>   on standard output. When arguments are
>   supplied, an alias is defined for each
>   name whose value is given. A trailing
>   space in value causes the next word to
>   be checked for alias substitution when
>   the alias is expanded. For each name
>   in the argument list for which no
>   value is supplied, the name and value
>   of the alias is printed. Alias returns
>   true unless a name is given for which
>   no alias has been defined.

Comment: Tried it out, created a file at the location but it doesn't seem to work. Comes up with conMy: command not found. Not sure if it's a permission thing or just a server setting.

Comment: In your home dir (on the server) do "ls -a". See if there are any files like .bashrc, .profile or .bash_profile. These names start with . (a dot). Also, check which shell you're using with "echo $SHELL"

Comment: Theres a .bash_history and a .bash_profile (but I created that one with touch). $SHELL = /bin/bash

Comment: Well, then it should work. What exactly did you put in .bash_profile?

Comment: <pre>alias conMy='mysql -u username -h hostname -p'</pre>

That's it. Only text in the file (with hostname/username blanked out. hostname has hyphens and dots in it if that'd affect it at all)

Comment: Have you re-logged after changing that file?

Comment: Woooo! That did it. Thanks a bunch for the help, you've saved me a lot of time ;D

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to ssh. You have to set the variables in your shell.